# Combining Sets of 9 Columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that is 9 rows and 54 columns of various numbers. I want to combine the values from the first nine columns into one long column in R. Then the same for each of the following 9 columns until I just have 6 long columns. It seems like this should be easy but none of the similar problems I've found online are working for my dataset.

Comment: How exactly should the columns be _combined_?

Comment: And how exactly does your dataset look? Perhaps you can paste a small subset of your data here using `dput(yourdatasetname)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Assuming your `data.frame` is `df`:

```
as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(df),ncol=6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the variables to be concatenated, I'll turn 6 variables into 2 by 3 instead of 54 into 6 by 9 to demonstrate:

```
library(dplyr) # load package
library(tidyr) # load package

set.seed(1839) # set seed for replication
d <- tibble(x=rnorm(5), y=rnorm(5), z=rnorm(5), # create data frame
            a=rnorm(5), b=rnorm(5), c=rnorm(5)) # create data frame
```

Data frame looks like:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
           x          y          z          a          b            c
       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
1  1.0127014 -0.7025836  0.2956671 -0.3563105  1.3232985 -0.367605941
2 -0.6845605 -1.4586245  0.3016737  1.6841862 -0.6978598  1.608783979
3  0.3492607  0.1987113 -0.0945271  1.3073516 -0.3971175 -1.074255857
4 -1.6245010  1.0544690 -0.2790357  0.4352904  0.1711608  0.006136588
5 -0.5162476 -0.7112214  0.1681388  1.4536406  0.6854223 -0.442184403
```

Now use the `unite` function:

```
d <- d %>% # take data frame
  unite(var1, x:z, sep="; ") %>% # combine with semicolon and space in between
  unite(var2, a:c, sep="; ") # combine with semicolon and space in between
```

And the resulting data frame:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
                                                       var1                                                      var2
*                                                     <chr>                                                     <chr>
1   1.01270138785465; -0.702583610804264; 0.295667113228807   -0.356310525447978; 1.3232984913192; -0.367605940884135
2  -0.684560547695866; -1.45862451298252; 0.301673721520136    1.68418623459335; -0.697859769158927; 1.60878397933222
3 0.349260666732972; 0.198711282685719; -0.0945271007709923    1.3073516257469; -0.397117503476358; -1.07425585717004
4   -1.62450101506933; 1.05446901501249; -0.279035672484018 0.435290405700962; 0.171160804752516; 0.00613658799909723
5 -0.516247631722097; -0.711221362746118; 0.168138783952361   1.45364055160547; 0.685422280037675; -0.442184403125297
```